# Unable to recognize bootable usb

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, bios

I formatted a USB to a bootable usb with windows 10. Now when I enter BIOS mode, this bootable usb is not recognized. First, I tried the fat32 type, but the .iso file from windows is to large to be copied on the usb drive. Then, I tried the exFat type and the NTFS type, but they are both not recognized when I want to choose them as the prior boot option. I tried both enabling and disabling legacy mode, and I disabled secure boot and fast boot. I could not find anything about CSM in my boot menu (asus rog strix). Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For UEFI mode that is the only one that should be used in any modern UEFI hardware, all you need to do it to extract the ISO (with 7Zip) to a NTFS formatted USB dongle of at least 8GB.

For better results download and create the installation media directly using the automated Windows Media creation tool in a Windows machine. With some effort and know how it can be done in a Windows VM running in any host OS.

Other than that, in Ubuntu, MKUSB or WoeUSB have been used successfully even with the new, overweight, non-standard Microsoft ISOs.